# which is the best way to externalize a database configuration on a desktop app?

Tags: java, eclipse, properties, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I'm working in a desktop app, and we're using Eclipse RCP with EclipseLink.
All my database configuration is inside a class, but I'll need these thing (database URL, password, username) configurable.
Which is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be to use some simple property file and java.util.Properties to read it.

You can read the file from classpath, e.g:

```
Class.getResourceAsStream ("resource.properties");
```

Comment: i'll put a .properties file inside a invisible folder on user's home, combined with the encryption tip from @Matthew Farwell. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

The standard way is to have a properties (either java.util.Properties or XML) file in which is stored the database details. This can be writeable by the user of course, and passwords stored in such a file need to be encrypted.

It's a nice idea to give the user a means of setting these from the application rather than having to edit the file manually though.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answers already given I would suggest externalizing the reference to the properties file by specifying it as a command-line option, e.g:

```
java my.app.MainClass -Ddb.config=/path/to/db.properties
```

You can then grab the path like so:

```
final String dbConfigPath = System.getProperty("db.config");
```